# Having trouble with printf statments

Tags: java, printf

I am writing a program where it takes a file and tries to use data from the file in order to create an output.

this is the program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;


public class WebberProjectTest
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("portlandvip.txt"));
while(scanner.hasNext()) 
{
String line = scanner.nextLine();
String[] words = line.split(" "); 

if(words[3].equals("Court")) 
{
int a = 75 * Integer.parseInt(words[2]);
System.out.printf(" " + words[0] + " " + words[1] + " $%.2f\n ", a);
}

if(words[3].equals("Box")) 
{
int a = 50 * Integer.parseInt(words[2]);
System.out.printf(" " + words[0] + " " + words[1] + " $%.2f\n", a);
}

if(words[3].equals("Club")) 
{
int a = 40 * Integer.parseInt(words[2]);
System.out.printf(" " + words[0] + " " + words[1] + " $%.2f\n", a);
}
}       


 }    
}
```

and this is the error that prints out:

```
Loras Tyrell Loras Tyrell $java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f !=           java.lang.Integer
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)
at WebberProjectTest.main(WebberProjectTest.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

I have no idea what i am doing wrong with the printf statement, and any help would be nice.

(This is a duplicate of [Having trouble with program output an printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23172460/having-trouble-with-program-output-an-printf) but i felt like this was a seperate quesion from what i was originally asking and no one was answering my question so i made a new post to have this question answered)

Comment: **Please read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)**.

Answer (score 2):

`%f` is used to print `float`s. Since `a` is an `int`, you should be using `%d`. E.g.:

```
int a = 75 * Integer.parseInt(words[2]);
System.out.printf(" " + words[0] + " " + words[1] + " $%d%n ", a);
```

Comment: how do i have the output rounded to 2 decimal places though? i tried $.2%d%n , $%d%.2n , $%.2d%n , etc, but it isnt printing as decimal rounded like $400.00

Comment: Alternatively, you could print with `%f` like you did, but store `a` as a `float`.